# Mostar / Ocultar jQuery

Tags: php, html, jquery, datatables

Quiero ocultar y mostrar una columna de mi grid en especifico esta tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la variable que crea las tablas

```
$gridhead = "{ title: 'Nombre',            field: 'name'  },
             { title: 'Apellido',            field: 'apel'  },
             { title: 'Rol',                  field: 'role'  },
             { title: 'Producto',           field: 'product' },
             { title: 'Venta',              field: 'vnta', type: 'number', format: '{0:c}' },
             { title: '% Participación',      field: 'part', type: 'number', format: '{0:p}'  },
             { title: 'Cuentas Atendidas',  field: 'cnts', type: 'number' },
             { title: 'Cuenta Promedio',      field: 'cntp', type: 'number', format: '{0:c}' },";
if($doComs){
    $gridhead.= "{ title: 'Comensales Atendidos', field: 'coms', type: 'number' },
                 { title: 'Comensal Promedio',  field: 'comp', type: 'number', format: '{0:c}' }";
}
```

y este es el codigo que llena los campos de la table en cuestion

```
 $gridson.="{
    name: '".$user["nombre"]."',
    apel: '".$user["apellido"]."',
    role: '".$user["rol"]."',
    product: '".$user["productos"]."',
    vnta: '$".number_format($user["venta"],2)."',
    part: '".number_format($particip,2)."%',
    cnts: '".$user["cuentas"]."',
    cntp: '$".number_format($cuentasP,2)."'";
    if($doComs){
        $comensP = $user['venta']/$user["comens"];
        $comensT = $comensT + $user["comens"];
        $gridson.=",
        coms: '".$user["comens"]."',
        comp: '$".number_format($comensP,2)."'";
    }
```

Y la condicion seria que cuando el option seleccione detallado muestre la tabla de Producto si escogo cualquier otro no la muestre.

el codigo del option es:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
            <label>Tipo de Reporte</label>
    <select name="reporFind" id="reporFind">

            <option value="0"<? if($tipoReporte == 0)  echo ' selected: '?>>Global </option>
            <option value="1" <? if($tipoReporte == 1) echo ' selected: ' ?>>Detallado </option>
            </select>
            </div>
            <?
            $col = $col + 2;
            $jsvars .= 'var tipoReporte = $("#tipoReporte").val();
            ';
            if($fcount!==1) $params .= ',';
            $params .= 'tipoReporte';
            $fTipoCuenta = false;

    }
```

Nota:

intente colocar

```
$tipoReporte.Hide();
if($tipoReporte == 1){
 $tipoReporte.Show();
}
else {
$tipoReporte.Hide();
}
```

pero no funciono

Comment: Puedes añadir todo el codigo ?,  no veo donde haces el echo de la tabla   , tiene algun id la columna o alguna clase ?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes ocultar/mostrar cualquier elemento HTML con jQuery usando esto:

```
  jQuery("col-md-2").css("display", "none");
```

"none" oculta el elenco HTML y sus hijos y "Block" lo vuelve a mostrar, solo tendrías que poner un listener para el selector de detalles para que cuando el usuario elija esa opción muestre el div y cuando cambie a alguna otra lo oculte

Comment: Pero en que parte del codigo debo agregarlo, ademas como le digo que tabla es la que se va a a esconder o mostrar la condicion seria que solo se mostrara cuando diga detallado

`option value="1" <? if($tipoReporte == 1) echo ' selected: ' ?>>Detallado </option>`

Answer (score 0):

Solamente coloque una condicion que cuando $tipoReporte fuera igual a detallado me mostrara el grid con detalles si la condicion falla lo muestra normal

```
if($tipoReporte == 'Detallado'){
    $gridhead = "{ title: 'Nombre',            field: 'name'  },
             { title: 'Apellido',            field: 'apel'  },
             { title: 'Rol',                  field: 'role'  },
             { title: 'Producto',           field: 'product' },
             { title: 'Venta',              field: 'vnta', type: 'number', format: '{0:c}' },
             { title: '% Participación',      field: 'part', type: 'number', format: '{0:p}'  },
             { title: 'Cuentas Atendidas',  field: 'cnts', type: 'number' },
             { title: 'Cuenta Promedio',      field: 'cntp', type: 'number', format: '{0:c}' },";
            }
            else{

$gridhead = "{ title: 'Nombre',            field: 'name'  },
             { title: 'Apellido',            field: 'apel'  },
             { title: 'Rol',                  field: 'role'  },
             { title: 'Venta',              field: 'vnta', type: 'number', format: '{0:c}' },
             { title: '% Participación',      field: 'part', type: 'number', format: '{0:p}'  },
             { title: 'Cuentas Atendidas',  field: 'cnts', type: 'number' },
             { title: 'Cuenta Promedio',      field: 'cntp', type: 'number', format: '{0:c}' },";

            }
```

Gracias por su tiempo.